# ComAutomationFactory

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, types, comautomationfactory

Im trying to use the ComAutomationFactory class in VB .NET the example im working from is c# and is working fine but my project doesnt compile and says this class is not defined??

also what is the return type? in the c# example it returns a type of dynamic but this type does not exist in vb .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you're sample is old, according to this blog:

http://silverlight-essentials.blogspot.com/2010/03/breaking-changes-in-com-interop-between.html

It's changed name as:

The class `ComAutomationFactory` has been renamed to `AutomationFactory`.
Additionally you have to reference `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation` for this class.

Regarding the return type, the answer to this question has a solution:

[Iterating over Word Document Fields using ComAutomationFactory in Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976503/iterating-over-word-document-fields-using-comautomationfactory-in-silverlight-4)